Compute Integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x \cos(x) \sin(x)}{1 - \cos^2(x) \sin^2(x)} \, dx$
How to compute the following integral?
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x \cos(x) \sin(x)}{1 - \cos^2(x) \sin^2(x)} \, dx$$
I've tried some methods like departing it into $\frac{x}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-\sin x\cos x}-\frac{1}{1+\sin x\cos x}\right)$, but it doesn't seem work :(

Perhaps replace $\sin x \cos x$ by $\frac 1 2 \sin 2 x$ and so reduce the partial fractions down to the more tractable $\frac 1 {2 (1 - \sin 2 x) }$ and $\frac 1 {2 (1+ \sin 2 x) }$. Then you have https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Primitive_of_x_over_1_minus_Sine_of_a_x and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Primitive_of_x_over_1_plus_Sine_of_a_x.

@PrimeMover That's not correct, for it actually gets $\frac{1}{2-sin2x}$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x \cos(x) \sin(x)}{1 - \cos^2(x) \sin^2(x)} , dx\overset{x=\frac\pi2-t}{=}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\big(\frac\pi2-t\big) \cos(t) \sin(t)}{1 - \cos^2(t) \sin^2(t)} , dt$$
$$\Rightarrow I=
\frac\pi4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(x) \sin(x)}{1 - \cos^2(x) \sin^2(x)} , dx=\frac\pi8\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(2x)}{1 - \frac14\sin^2(2x)} , dx$$
$$=\frac\pi8\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(t)}{\frac34 + \frac14\cos^2(t)} , dt=\frac\pi2\int_0^1\frac{dx}{3+x^2}$$

@Svyatoslav That's quite impressive! How does it come to you of replacing $x$ into $\frac{\pi}{2}-t$?

So go and finish it then

This is a usual way to get rid of $x$ in trigonometric integrals - if the symmetry allows us to do it.

@Svyatoslav Thanks! That helps a lot :D

In the same vein, substituting $x\to x+\frac\pi4$ yields$$\int_{-\tfrac\pi4}^\tfrac\pi4\frac{\left(x+\frac\pi4\right) \cdot \frac12\cos(2x)}{1-\frac14\cos^2(2x)},dx$$that is, the integral of an odd plus an even function over an interval centered at $0$, so that only the even part survives.

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x \cos x \sin x}{1-\cos ^2 x \sin ^2 x} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) \sin x \cos x}{1-\sin ^2 x \cos ^2 x} d x \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x \cos x}{1-\sin ^2 x \cos ^2 x} d x-I \\&= \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x \cos x}{1-\sin ^2 x \cos ^2 x} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Letting $s=\sin^2 x$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{d s}{(2 s-1)^2+3} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4 \sqrt{3}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 s-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]_0^1 \\
& =\frac{\pi^2}{12 \sqrt{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$

For the antiderivative only.
$$I=\frac{x \cos(x) \sin(x)}{1 - \cos^2(x) \sin^2(x)} \, dx=\int \frac{4 x \sin (2 x)}{7+\cos (4 x)}\,dx$$
$$x=\frac t 2 \quad \implies \quad I=\int \frac{t \sin (t)}{7+\cos (2 t)}\,dt$$
One integration by parts with $u=t$ let us with
$$v=\int  \frac{ \sin (t)}{7+\cos (2 t)}\,dt=-\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{1+2 \tan
   ^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$
The antiderivative of $v$ can be computed (have a look here).
